# SQL: return values when PK equals two specific values in two different rows on the same field

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to return the rows where the SAME id is both in 23 and 12 (this is just an example... I have 30K records)

```
ID: ASDJKGFJKBQGW Number:23
ID: ASDJKGFJKBQGW Number:12
ID: ASDJKGFJKBQGW Number:43
ID: ASDJKGFJKBQGW Number:67
ID: ASDJKGFJKBQGW Number:32
```

Doing: `select * from table where Number=23 and Number=12` won't do.

Do I need to declare a variable for the ID and do a while loop?

```
While @ID is the same
select * from table where Number = 23 and Number = 12
```

Thanks

Comment: You need OR instead of AND. It's clear that a Number has 2 values in the same row...
Anyway The best way is IN statement:

SELECT * 
FROM table 
WHERE Number IN (12, 23, ... , ..)

Comment: plz add an output in your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Select * from table1
Where number in (14,23) and id in(
Select id from table1 
Where number in (14,23)
Group by id
Having count(distinct number) = 2)
```

The inner subquery uses the having clause that gives the exact number of rows 2. Together with the distinct you are sure to get these rows

Comment: because you use * in the outer select, you will still have two rows (one for each value of number)

Comment: Getting close, however it also returns rows where number is not 14 or 23. 
I just need to select * where the same ID and number is 14 and same id and number is 23 only. I don't want the other rows where the number is something else. 
Can this be done?

Comment: @DakTengu . . . Just add `and number in (14, 23)` if you only want those rows.

Comment: Cha You're a star!!! This works like a charm thank you. The other script works as well but only displays the single row per 14 or 23 and not both of them. 

How should I say to DELETE * where 23 exists and number is 14?

Comment: Delete from table1
Where number = 14 and id in( 
Select id from table1 
Where number in (14,23) and id in(
Select id from table1 
Where number in (14,23)
Group by id
Having count(distinct number) = 2)

Comment: I don't think you need two subqueries. One will do: `Delete from table1 Where number = 14 and id in(Select id from table1 Where number in (14,23) Group by id Having count(distinct number) = 2)`

Answer (score 0):

this should do the trick

```
select * from table where Number in (23, 12)
```

or

```
select * from table where Number = 23 or Number = 12
```

EDIT

something like this:

```
   select id from table where number in (23,12) 
   group by id
   having count(*) = 2
```

if the numbers can appear multiple times for each id then you may use a subquery

```
   select id from 
   ( select distinct id, number from table ) x
   where number in (23,12) 
   group by id
   having count(*) = 2
```

Comment: Doesn't that return either 23 or 12 or 23 and 12? 
How do I specifically ask for 23 and 12?

Comment: What output did you want - not sure I understand the question?

Comment: I want to see the ID where Number = 23 and Number = 12 (so it will return two rows). 
Your statement is fine here.. but dealing with 30k rows I will have multiple occurances where it will only return the ID where the Number is only 23 or the number is only 12.